# Some commands in init.el don't run on startup, but others seem to run fine

Tags: init-file

I am having a very weird issue with my init.el file. At startup, some of the commands in it run fine (so I know Emacs is able to pick the correct file), but others only run when I manually load the file using `M-x load-file RET ~/.emacs.d/init.el RET` (so I know those commands are syntactically correct as well). Here is a working example:

```
(setq package-enable-at-startup nil)
(setq doc-view-continuous t)
(package-initialize)


(unless (package-installed-p 'use-package)
  (package-refresh-contents)
  (package-install 'use-package))

(eval-when-compile
  (require 'use-package))
(use-package yasnippet
  :config
  (yas-reload-all)
  (yas-minor-mode 1)
  :ensure t)
(use-package auto-complete
  :ensure t
  :config
  (auto-complete-mode 1)
  )

; The following command is not run at startup. But runs when I load the file manually.
(setq line-spacing 0.3)

(yas-minor-mode 1)

(global-display-line-numbers-mode)
;If I remove the next command, startup line numbers are no longer relative, but they are with it.
(setq display-line-numbers-type 'relative)
```

I tried removing the top commands (all upto to line-spacing), but on removing them even the line numbers were no longer working on startup.

I am using Mac OS X Mojave. `M-x emacs-version RET` gives the following:
`GNU Emacs 26.3 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-09-02`. I had installed it along with AucTex.

I am fairly new with Emacs and Lisp, so please let me know if I should provide some more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your code is running. The trouble is, `line-spacing` is a buffer-local variable. From the help for this variable (which I found by `C-h v line-spacing`):

> Automatically becomes buffer-local when set.

That means changing the value of the variable only effects line spacing in the current buffer, not all buffers.

In order to change the default value of `line-spacing`, you need to change it using the Customization interface: `M-x customize-variable lines-spacing`.

Comment: I see! That makes a lot of sense! Can you elaborate on how to identify buffer-local commands. It turns out even the commands on autocomplete-mode and yas-minor-mode are only running locally, and I want to run them globally

Comment: I don't know of an easy way to get a list of all buffer-local variables. It's something that comes up case by case, whenever an individual developer wants to limit a feature to a single buffer at a time. This is common for things that only make sense for particular file types. Once you're aware of it, you'll know to pay attention to this detail when reading documentation.

Comment: You don't always need to use `Customize` to set default values for buffer-local variables. Often (usually?) you can do  `(setq-default local-variable value)` to set the global default of <variable> to <value>.